# AWS Pinpoint send email notification using Java

Tags: aws-pinpoint

I am just getting started with Amazon Pinpoint and I am trying to use the AWS Java SDK to send a direct message to an endpoint that has an email address.  I am certain that the endpoint ID exists and the email address has been verified.

Here is the response I am receiving:

```
    {
      SendUsersMessageResponse: {
        ApplicationId: ab9efe03c5654594bd55aee0589d9a60,
        Result: {
          u777={
            777={
              Address: xxxxxxxx@abc.com,
              DeliveryStatus: PERMANENT_FAILURE,
              StatusCode: 400,
              StatusMessage: Requestmustincludemessageemailmessage.,
            }
          }
        }
      }
  }
```

Here is my source code:

```
DefaultMessage defaultMsg = new DefaultMessage()
        .withBody("The body");
DirectMessageConfiguration directMsgConfig = new DirectMessageConfiguration()
        .withDefaultMessage(defaultMsg);
Map<String, EndpointSendConfiguration> users = new HashMap<>();
users.put("u777", new EndpointSendConfiguration());

SendUsersMessageRequest msgReq = new SendUsersMessageRequest()
        .withMessageConfiguration(directMsgConfig)
        .withUsers(users);
SendUsersMessagesRequest msgsReq = new SendUsersMessagesRequest()
        .withApplicationId(applicationID)
        .withSendUsersMessageRequest(msgReq);

SendUsersMessagesResult msgsRes = client.sendUsersMessages(msgsReq);
```

I can see the error says I must include an email message, but looking through the documentation and developer guide I can not figure out what I need to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

direct (transactional) email messaging is currently not supported on Amazon Pinpoint. Please follow the AWS Messaging and Targeting blog to learn about new features that we are continuously building  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/